# How to put author affiliations to the bottom left corner in a two-column page

Tags: two-column, affiliation

See the template below. The affiliation looks like footnote integrated into text (actually, this is literally the saying in the journal format document).
[image]

Comment: Is that a MSWord format?

Comment: Yes, it is. Only a formatted Word document is given.

Comment: @BsHe: This site is dedicated to content related to (La)TeX and related systems. This excludes MS Word. Do you have any (La)TeX problems specific to the template?

Comment: @Werner I think that Bs He wants to create the same with LaTeX, so he uses MS Word to explain his idea.

Comment: @Werner I want to create the same format in latex. Thanks.

Comment: See `\thanks`..

Answer (score 1):

The following somewhat replicates the template you're showing. It's not automated, but that can be done if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry,sectsty,etoolbox}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\geometry{
  margin = 1in,
  twocolumn
}

\sectionfont{\normalfont\large\scshape\centering}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\space}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\vskip 1em{\large \@date}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\par\textbf{\itshape Abstract}---\ignorespaces}
  {\par\medskip}
\newenvironment{keywords}
  {\par\textbf{\itshape Keywords}---\ignorespaces}
  {\par\medskip}

\title{Preparation of Papers - Paper Title}
\author{%
  AuthorName Lastname%
  \rlap{\textsuperscript{1}},
  AuthorName Lastname%
  \rlap{\textsuperscript{2}},
  AuthorName Lastname%
  \rlap{\textsuperscript{3}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[\maketitle]

\footnotetext[1]{AuthorName Lastname is with the National Institute of Standards and Technology,
  Boulder, CO 80305 USA (correspondence author's phone: XXX-XXX-XXXX; email: who@cares.com}
\footnotetext[2]{AuthorName Lastname was with Rice University, Houston, TX 77005 USA.
  He is now with the Department of Physics, Colorado State University, Fort Collins,
  CO 80523 USA (email: who@cares.com)}
\footnotetext[3]{AuthorName Lastname is with the Electrical Engineering Department, University
  of Colorado, Boulder, CO 80309 USA, on leave from the National Research Institute
  for Metals, Tsukuba, Japan (email: who@cares.com)}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
  About four key words or phrases in alphabetical order, separated by commas.
\end{keywords}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Procedure for Paper Submission}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Review Stage}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Figures}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Document Modification}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Copyright Form}
\lipsum[6]

\section{Math}
\lipsum[7]

\section{Units}
\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```